# How to have a button refresh the page within jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

All I am trying to do is get my "refresh" button to simple refresh the page upon click, but my coding below is not allowing me to do so, I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

<script>
function swapButton() {
    var b = $('#button');
    b.text('Done');
    b.buttonMarkup({ icon: "check" });
    b.button('refresh');
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="header" data-posiition="fixed" id="header" data-theme="a">
    <a data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" id="button" onclick="swapButton()">Refresh</a>
    <h1>&copy; 2013 | EHU</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.button('refresh');
The following methods apply only to form buttons, Link-based buttons do not have any associated methods.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

So the only solution is to use form buttons(